# Переход с камеры на хиб файл

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Почему, если с кнопки переходить из сториборда на хиб файл вот так работает:

```
 - (IBAction)xibButton:(id)sender {
 LangViewController *imageController = [[LangViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:imageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

а если с камеры чтоб открывался сразу хиб вайл с фоткой такой код уже не работает, пишет:
Attempt to present <LangViewController: 0x13764fa60> on <UINavigationController>
Код выглядит

```
     -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
UIImage*image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   [_imagePlay setImage:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   LangViewController *imageController = [[LangViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:imageController animated:YES completion:nil];
imageController.image1= _imagePlay.image;
```

}

у меня хиб в ландшафтной ориентации поэтому не нужно чтоб там появлялся навигейшин контроллер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пытаетесь презентовать экран от экрана, который сейчас не виден, то есть self.view сейчас перекрыто UIImagePickerController, либо презентуйте от него (imagePicker в смысле), что лично я бы не рекомендовал, либо сначала закройте его, а затем уже презентуйте новый экран от self:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       LangViewController *imageController = [[LangViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:imageController animated:YES completion:nil];
    imageController.image1= _imagePlay.image;
    }];
```

Comment: круто получилось, теперь только фотка во втором view не высвечивается---я там в дидлоуде на писал
    self.imageView.image=self.image1;
читал, как то через delegate нада, не подскажешь???